# Change Like Button If Signed In User Already Liked A Post

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I hope that all is well. I am trying to use a button to like a post/article posted by other users. I have created a const function called "getAPostLikeRecord()," which will return a list of users that like the individual post. However, if the user currently signed in liked the article, I would like to have the like button highlighted in a different color. Otherwise, it'll be the current color that it is. To be less confusing, I would like to know if the signed-in user already like a post and be able to let the signed-in user know that the post was already liked.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './Home.css'
//Components
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer';
//Dependencies
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate, useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
//Function
import VerificationCheck from "../../Functions/VerificationCheck";


const Home = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const userLoggedIn = VerificationCheck.CheckLogin();
    const loggedInUser = VerificationCheck.CheckUser();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [likes, setLikes] = useState([]);
    const [statusMessage, setStatusMessage] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        if (!userLoggedIn) {
            navigate('/Login', {
                state: {
                    previousUrl: location.pathname,
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            getAllPost();
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
    }, [userLoggedIn]);
    
    const getAllPost = () => {
        const url = process.env.REACT_APP_Backend_URL + '/post/get-post-record';

        Axios.post (url)
        .then ((response) => {
            const _data = response.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < _data.length; i++){
                _data[i].displayMore = false;
            }
            setPost(_data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setStatusMessage("Server Side Error");
        });
    }

        const getAPostLikeRecord = async (PostID) => {
            const url = process.env.REACT_APP_Backend_URL + '/post/get-like-record';
    
            await Axios.post (url, {PostsID : PostID})
            .then ((response) => {
                setLikes(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setStatusMessage("Server Side Error");
            });
        }    

    const handleShowMore = (post_id) => {
                
        const current_state = [...posts];
        const current_post = current_state.find(p => p.postsID === post_id);
      
        if(!current_post) {
            // couldn't find the post, ID's dont match
            return;
        }

        // replace the current state to the opposite
        current_post.displayMore = !current_post.displayMore;
        setPost(current_state);
    }

    const CommentRedirect = (postsID) => {
        navigate(`/Post/${postsID}`);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
            <div className='homeBody'>
                <div className="homeForm">
                    {isLoading ?
                    <>
                        <h1>Loading...</h1>
                    </>
                    :
                    <>
                        {statusMessage ? 
                        <>
                            <h1>{statusMessage}</h1>
                        </>
                        :
                        <>
                            {posts.map(uploadedPost => (
                                <table key={uploadedPost.postsID}>
                                    <tbody className="postData" key={uploadedPost.postsID}>
                                        <tr><td><a href={`/Post/${uploadedPost.postsID}`}><h1 className="title">{uploadedPost.postsTitle}</h1></a></td></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div className="authorDate">
                                                    <h2 className="author">Author: {uploadedPost.postsAuthor}</h2>
                                                    <h3 className="datetime">{uploadedPost.createdOn}</h3>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr><td className="btn"><button className="btn" onClick={() => handleShowMore(uploadedPost.postsID)}>{uploadedPost.displayMore ? "Show less" : "Show more"}</button></td></tr>
                                        <tr><td><p className="caption">{uploadedPost.displayMore ? uploadedPost.postsCaption : `${uploadedPost.postsCaption.substring(0, 250)}`}{uploadedPost.displayMore ? "" : "..."}</p></td></tr>
                                        <tr><td><button className="interaction">{uploadedPost.postsLikes} Likes</button> <button className="interaction" onClick={() => CommentRedirect(uploadedPost.postsID)}>{uploadedPost.postsComments} Comment</button> <button className="interaction">Share</button></td></tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            ))}
                        </>
                        }
                    </>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

UPDATE:
I have updated the getAPostLikeRecord() function in my code to change the color of the individual-like button for a post if the user has already liked a post. However, .find is returning as undefined for some reason...

```
    const getAPostLikeRecord = async (PostID) => {
        const url = process.env.REACT_APP_Backend_URL + '/post/get-like-record';

        await Axios.post (url, {
            PostsID : PostID
        })
        .then ((response) => {
            setLikes(response.data);

            if (response.data.length !== 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
                    response.data[i].didUserLike = false;
                }

                const current_state = [...likes];
                const current_likes = current_state.find(l => l.postsLikeAuthor.trim() === loggedInUser);

                console.log(current_likes)
                
                if(!current_likes) {
                    // couldn't find the post, ID's dont match
                    return;
                }
        
                // replace the current state to the opposite
                current_likes.didUserLike = !current_likes.didUserLike;
                setLikes(current_state);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setStatusMessage("Server Side Error");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this, sadly both require some backend and db changes and the easiest one is to set the likes record as follows:

```
{
  likes: [userId: string]
}
```

and in your back-end you can return a "liked" boolean by checking if the likes array contains the userId in the request.

The other way is to add a likedPosts table, and then check if the current post is in that likedPosts.

```
{
  likedPosts: [postId: string]
}
```

Comment: I will do this as a last resort.

Comment: The second one is better imo as it scales much better and can be used later on to show liked posts of any user, it shouldn't be that hard to implement now that I think about it, you just modify your backend code that executes when a user likes a post so that it adds the post id to the users liked posts table.
What stack are you using for backend and what db? if you don't mind me asking

Comment: I am using ASP.Net Core 6, or C#, and MS SQL

Comment: I think I am still confused on how to set this up... so the db returns three things, a postLikeID, a postID, and the person that liked a post... Where would I go from here

Comment: what is the postLikeId? and if you have the id of everyone that liked a post you can just query that with the userId and if it's there you can send it to the front end to change the like icon.

Comment: its the id of the data on the like table. And if I understand, your saying if the id of the signedin user is detected in the result, flip the icon?

Comment: If the like table has userIds then yes check if it contains userId but this isn't very scalable if say later on you want to show a list of liked posts by a certain user. 

What I'd recommend is to have a likedPosts table that is related to the user, so every user has a table of likedPosts. 

But again the easier one is to have a table of users who liked the post which I'm assuming is what you have implemented as suggested by the other reply.Sadly I don't know C# so I can't help you there but if you share a console log of what your API returns I can help you with the front end code.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, you should give a user a column containing posts they like while also giving a post a column containing users who like it. It’s a bit complicated but yet simple.

> A post has a list of users who like it.
> A user has a list of posts they like.

With the separation of concerns, other users can know how many likes a post has while a user can know which posts they like.

I assumed you can control the implementation on the backend but if you can’t but will only approach it via the frontend, it won’t turn out well.

Comment: This seems like it will work the best. I will try this in a few hours and will let you know! Thanks!

Comment: Don’t worry I’ll be online for a while. It’s my break time 

Comment: While this did work, it highlighted all the buttons like I assumed it would. I am posting the updated code.